# Usage of GraphQL for Neo4j and Ontotext GraphDB simultaneously

Tags: java, neo4j, graphql, graphdb, graphql-java

I have two instances of two different database engines (Neo4j and Ontotext GraphDB) and I want to create common interface in GraphQL for these databases.

I want to use Java to create endpoint with GraphQL.

Should I use graphql-java library or do you recommend something else to merging usage of different database engines?

I looking for most flexible solution for this type of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL is designed to be a thin layer above your service layer. It is completely independent of the data storage you are using.

You ask to merge the access to your databases. This is actually a task for your service layer (which is simple java code. Could be backed by Spring for example). Your API layer will then consume your services. GraphQL can be your API layer or part of it.

You should consider either using REST or GraphQL. But having two different databases is not a deciding factor, as this is not the concern for either. You will be fine with both of them. Read this: [GraphQL vs REST](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/graphql-vs-rest-5d425123e34b)

If you decide to use GraphQL and Java. graphql-java is your only choice (and it is a good one).

Comment: What about other graphql libraries for Java?: https://github.com/chentsulin/awesome-graphql#lib-java
Is any worth to use?

Comment: They are not actually GraphQL implementations, but just adding features, like annotation support etc. to your graphql-java. Stick to graphql-java and add other librarys as you need and you will be fine :)

Comment: For some reason Java related libs are being woefully misrepresented on awesome-graphql, with PRs rotting for months. Check out https://github.com/graphql-java/awesome-graphql-java for a much more up-to-date view of the Java ecosystem.

Comment: Beautiful answer, by the way. Too many libraries, articles and posts suggest the terrible design where GraphQL is translated directly to the DB query, negating half the benefits of GraphQL and good practices.